# Adding dynamic columns in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a directory containing around 96 CSV files each containing a variable number of columns in range of [19000 to 23088]. I am trying to open each of the 96 files and copy the first row from them and paste them to an already created CSV file. The code that I am using is as follows-

```
# Read CSV file-
# This is the file to which the content has to be added
audio_training = pd.read_csv("Training-Audio.csv")

audio_training.shape
# (96, 23089)
# Rows are from 0 to 95


# Now copy each file's content (1 line to 'audio_training' DataFrame)-

# Copy all movie names from 'Training-Audio' CSV file-
# 'Movie_Name' column contains names of all CSV files in directory
mov_audio = audio_training.loc[:, "Movie_Name"]

# To keep track of current position in 'Training-Audio.csv' DataFrame-
row_num = 0

# Open each movie (CSV) file and copy the first line to 'Training-Audio.csv'-
for movie in mov_audio:
    print("\nCurrent movie being processed: {0}\n".format(movie))

    # mov_csv = pd.read_csv(movie + ".csv")
    mov_csv = pd.read_csv(movie)
    # mov_csv.iloc[0,:]

    # Copy first line from each CSV and paste it to 'Training-Audio' DataFrame represented by 'audio_training' Python variable-
    audio_training.iloc[row_num,:] = mov_csv.iloc[0:,]
    row_num += 1
```

Executing this code snippet gives the error-

> ValueError: Incompatible indexer with DataFrame

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks !

Comment: What does the line `audio_training.iloc[row_num,:] = ` mean? and on what line does the error occur?

Comment: Could you provide us with your full traceback?

Comment: @JohnJeffersonBautista I edited the post to answer your query

Answer (score 0):

To update a single row, assign a series rather than a dataframe. Indexing with `slice(0, None)` or its more common representation `0:` returns a dataframe with one row, while indexing with `0` returns a series.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2], 'B': [3, 4], 'C': [5, 6]})
df_new = pd.DataFrame({'A': [7, 8], 'B': [9, 10], 'C': [11, 12]})

df.iloc[0, :] = df_new.iloc[0:, :]  # ValueError: Incompatible indexer with DataFrame
df.iloc[0, :] = df_new.iloc[0, :]   # WORKS

print(df)
#    A  B   C
# 0  7  9  11
# 1  2  4   6
```

To check this yourself, you can use `type`:

```
type(df_new.iloc[0:, :])  # pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
type(df_new.iloc[0, :])   # pandas.core.series.Series
```

Comment: The line 'audio_training.iloc[row_num, 1:] = mov_csv_nona.iloc[0, :]' is not copying any data. I don't know why it's not copying anything. Help?

Comment: Arun, that line isn't in my solution. Where did it come from? Does my answer help address the problem in your question?

Comment: OK, unfortunately I can't help answer as your new question is a different one (different code, different problem). Good luck!